# Create textarea value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a script in jQuery that generates a `table` in HTML. How can I put the contents of this table in a `textarea` so I can send it with PHP?

```js
function renderCart(items) {
  const $cart = document.querySelector(".cart")
  const $total = document.querySelector(".total")

  $cart.innerHTML = items.map((item) => `
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%;"><img src="img/${item.img}.jpg" class="img-responsive"></td>
      <td style="display: none;">${item.id}</td>
      <td>${item.name}</td>
      <td>${item.specs}</td>
      <td>${item.quantity}</td>
      <td style="width: 60px;"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
          onClick="cartLS.quantity(${item.id},1)">+</button>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 60px;"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-outline-primary"
          onClick="cartLS.quantity(${item.id},-1)">-</button>
      </td>
      <td class="text-right">€${item.price}</td>
      <td class="text-right"><Button class="btn btn-bestel" onClick="cartLS.remove(${item.id})">Verwijderen</Button></td>
    </tr>`).join("")

  $total.innerHTML = "€" + cartLS.total()
}

renderCart(cartLS.list())
cartLS.onChange(renderCart)
```

Comment: **Are you *sure***  that you want to submit an entire `<table>` with `<tr>`s and `<td>`s and with everything in it? That almost never makes sense. It would make a lot more sense to construct a JS object from the data inside `items`, convert that JS object to a JSON string, and then submit that to an API endpoint.

Comment: no actually it is the variables that have to be shown in a string

Comment: Ok, so then this applies: create a JS object from the data inside `items`, convert that JS object to a JSON string, and then submit that to an API endpoint. There are lots of tutorials (e.g. on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=jquery+send+data+to+api)) that can teach you how to do that. Stack Overflow does not offer tutorials or anything like it.